# sleep between 2 changes of style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a Simon game whit Javascript. I want that when I show the sequence of colors, do a sleep then I change the opacity to 0.3 and then sleep again and change te opacity of the color to 1 again.
But when I try it, it dont sleep, only wait when i put a alert or something that pause the execution.

My code is:

```
for(x = 0; x < cicleCount.length; x++) {
    cicleCount[x] = colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))];
    sleep(1000);
    document.getElementById(cicleCount[x]).style.opacity = 1;
    sleep(1000);
    document.getElementById(cicleCount[x]).style.opacity = 0.3;
}
```

My sleep() function:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I also try whit a setTimeout() but it dont work, it just execute all the code without any pause.

Comment: Can you post all the code? also the html etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using sleep() is called [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and isn't a good idea as causes unnecessary CPU load, and in the case of JavaScript it will block the UI thread.

You **do** need [Window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout), this runs a callback (function) after a set amount of time.

Without seeing your failed attempt at Window.setTimeout I can't provide any more information on why that didn't work. Please update your question.

However, I'm guessing you'd be better with window.setInterval() and some kind of clock which you can then increment as use to alternate the opacity. In the following code, if I've got it right x should go in the sequence 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, up to (cicleCount.length - 1), and the opacity should toggle 1, 0.3, 1, 0.3 etc.

```
var clock = 0;
var tick = function() {
   var x = (clock / 2) % cicleCount.length;
   cicleCount[x] = colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))];
   if (clock % 2 == 0) {
     document.getElementById(cicleCount[x]).style.opacity = 1;
   } else {
     document.getElementById(cicleCount[x]).style.opacity = 0.3;
   }
   clock++;
};
var timer = window.setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Use the following if you need to stop your animation later.

```
window.clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: It works, not the way i wanted but i can make changes to ajust it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way things work in a browser environment. Your brower display will not be refreshed during the execution of a Javascript function.

Besides, "sleeping" inside a piece of JavaScript code will basically freeze your page. Your browser will not respond to user inputs or other events until your code is done executing, which has great chances of annoying the viewers.

You will have to use timers to make the changes visible, so that the page can be updated between the different timer invokations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this this the setTimeout function:-

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(cicleCount[x]).style.opacity = 1;
  },1000);
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(cicleCount[x]).style.opacity = 0.3;
  },2000);
```